# Migrating SharePoint 2003 Web Apps and Portals to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

With SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010 no longer available the classic "SwingBridge" Approach is no longer available.

So how do I migrate SharePoint 2003 Farm to SharePoint Online say using a Third Party Tool.

I have an inventory of the SharePoint 2003 Farm.

How do I map the SharePoint 2003 Web Applications and Portal Sites to SharePoint Online. using say a third party tool such as ShareGate ?

Thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 0):

Your all custom solution will need to be re-created using new spfx model. Sharepoint  online doesn't support servers side solutions (.wsps) Then you can migrate the content with site creation using Sharegate. When the sites are ready you can either deploy your new custom solution to site app catalog or tenant app catalog (the latter will allow for them to be used across the tenant)

Comment: Hi Marek there are no custom solutions. I just have out of the box functionality.  Regards. Nigel